# Bitcoind and multiple users

Tags: bitcoind

I was wondering if anyone had advice for running bitcoind for multiple users. I obviously don't want users to get into other users transactions. As far as I can tell I'll need to run multiple instances of Bitcoind, but this is a terrible waste of bandwidth. Can I at least share the blockchain across users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoind allows you to house multiple and separate accounts in a single instance of the bitcoin client. Using the accounts feature is probably what you're looking for.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained

Comment: Is it possible to separate access to accounts for different Unix/Linux/Windows users? One daemon bitcoind, with many accounts?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, but I will try to answer. You need some sort of user account app on top of bitcoind to manage user authentication, account management, send/receive transactions. This app needs  to communicate with bitcoind.

Comment: Depreciated there is really no other way now other then running your own db and listening for wallet changes.